# How to enable brctl stp using python script?

Tags: python, mininet, stp

In mininet I am building a topology using `LinuxBridge` from `mininet.nodelib.LinuxBridge`) instead of `OVSKernelSwitch`.

```
s1 = net.addSwitch('s1', cls=LinuxBridge)
```

we can enable the stp of s1 from the command line by

```
brctl stp s1 on
```

How to enable the STP of the bridge `s1` directly from the writing python script instead of CLI.

For example, in OVSKernelSwitch we write:

```
s1.cmd('ovs-vsctl set bridge s1 stp-enable=true')
```

to enable the stp to break the loop in the network topology.

What is the `brctl stp enable` script?
I have tried with:

```
s1.cmd('brctl stp' , s1, 'on')
```

but it is unable to enable the stp.

Comment: Use subprocess to call `brctl stp s1 on` also dpctl http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1nodelib_1_1LinuxBridge.html#aa561b50171ac27e46f0e8ab7f6060d0c

Comment: Can you please give one example how to use subprocess to call "brctl stp s1 on"

Answer (score 1):

You could try using call procedures in your Python script. Example:

```
from subprocess import call
...
call('brctl stp s1 on')
```